# Can't render simple JSON's content in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use React-Redux to render the content of a small JSON.

I'm able to get the content via an Action :
(part of actions.js)

```
export const getUsersCount = () => {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        connectBack.get('users/count', {
            headers: { 
                'Authorization': getState().current_user.token
            }
        })
        .then( response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            dispatch(countUsers(response.data))
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log('Count ', error)
        })
    }
}


export const countUsers= (users) => {
    return {
        type: 'COUNT_USERS',
        payload: users
    }
}
```

The console will correctly render the content of response.data (in this case : {users: 6}).

Then I want to render it on a simple page but it's undefined, I'm missing something...

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getUnfulfilledCount, getUsersCount } from './../../tools/actions'


class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    
    render () {
        let statsUsers = this.props.usersCount()
        console.log(statsUsers)

    return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                        Dashboard <br/>
                        Number of registered users: <br/>
                        {statsUsers}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        usersCount: () => { dispatch(getUsersCount()) }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard)
```

In addition to it, I've got the reducer set as follow:

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes'


const initialState = {
    users:[]
} 

const reducer = (state = initialState, action ) => {
switch (action.type) {
case actionTypes.COUNT_USERS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    users: action.payload 
                }
```

Where actionTypes.js is :

```
export const COUNT_USERS = 'COUNT_USERS'
```

The exact render from the console :
undefined  Dashboard.js:12
{users: 6} actions.js:315
Obviously on the display the variable is just skipped as statsUsers is undefined:
"Number of registered users:"

Comment: What does your `getUsersCount` action creator look like? It's possible that it's not returning what Redux needs in order to dispatch the action properly. Can you update your question to include that file too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by my action creator :( I've added the reducer as well

Comment: Check out [the documentation on actions](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions), as it explains what an action creator is. Your `countUsers` function in `actions.js` is actually an action creator.

You should be importing your action type and using that in `actions.js` instead of hard-coding `COUNT_USERS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem lies in how you are mapping the resultant data back to the Dashboard component. You have a call to `mapStateToProps` that is empty, and a call to `mapDispatchToProps` that isn't necessary. I would remove the latter, and map the `users` property from the store in the props where you can access it in the Dashboard component, then render `this.props.users` instead.

Also note that by having your `render` function call `usersCount`, which maps to a call to `dispatch(getUsersCount())`, you're making an API call inside your `render` function. Making API calls while rendering is kind of a big no-no, and should be done in another place like `componentDidMount`.

See working Codepen [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-violet-9fjfx). It rewrites a *little* bit of your code, and adds a feature of an emulated delayed network response.

Answer (score 0):

Code not enough for understand, Maybe this example will help you.

```js
const myJsonData = [
  {0: {name: "Amoos John Ghouri"}},
  {1: {name: "GMK Hussain"}},
  {2: {name: "Talib Hussain"}}
];

class DemoApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
        const items = this.props.myJsonData.map((d,i) => (<li>{d[i].name}</li>));

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <DemoApp myJsonData={myJsonData} />,
  DemoAppDiv
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="DemoAppDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't really help as it's not react-redux, sorry. What else can I provide ? When I access the page "Dashboard" the console displays correctly " {users: 6}" for the console.log in action.js but doesn't for the console.log of the dashboard.js (it returns "Undefined").